# Retrieve data of Logged in user from other table through LINQ

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is my **ViewModel** where i've added two of my tables. **Account_Detail** (im getting login from this table). **Basic_Detail** (I need to retrieve data from this table after user logs in, through **Session**)

```
 public class BasicAccountView
{

    public Account_Details Account_Details { get; set; }
    public Basic_Details Basic_Details { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my **login** code, I've got both **Name** and **ID** in their respective Session variables

```
public ActionResult Index(Account_Details log)
    {

        var obj = db.Account_Details.Where(u => u.Name.Equals(log.Name) && u.Password.Equals(log.Password)).FirstOrDefault();
        Session["Account"] = log;

        if (obj != null)
        {

            Session["loginid"] = obj.U_ID;
            Session["name"] = obj.Name;
            Session["email"] = obj.Email;
            return RedirectToAction("Verify");
        }

        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Login code is all okay and get going, even **Session** is working fine, they're retrieving **Name** of logged in user. Though, scenario is like, I need to join this Account and Basic table, so that I can get details of logged in user from **Basic_Detail** table. here is my join query, but it ain't working, showing **nothing** at all.

```
public ActionResult Verify()
    {
        var Result = (from o in db.Basic_Details
                      join od in db.Account_Details on o.User_ID equals od.U_ID
                      where o.FirstName == this.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name
                      select new BasicAccountView { Basic_Details = o, Account_Details = od }).ToList();
        //var Result = (from o in db.Basic_Details
        //              join od in db.Account_Details on o.User_ID equals od.U_ID
        //              select new Basic_Details { FirstName = od.Name }).ToList();

        return View(Result);
    }
```

View of **Verify** Action

```
@model IEnumerable<Matrimonial.Models.BasicAccountView>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Verify";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Main.cshtml";
}
<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

@foreach(var item in Model)
{
 <td>@item.Basic_Details.FirstName</td>
 <td>@item.Basic_Details.LastName</td>
 <td>@item.Basic_Details.MaritalStatus</td>
 <td>@item.Basic_Details.Religion</td>


}
```

**UPDATE - ISSUE RESOLVED**
Just get Session["loginid"] into other variable and compare it to other table UserID from where you want to retrieve the data. I hope it'll help others with the same issue.

```
public ActionResult Verify()
    {
        BasicAccountView bav = new BasicAccountView();
        int userId = (int)Session["loginid"];
        var Result = from o in db.Basic_Details
                     join od in db.Account_Details on o.User_ID equals od.U_ID
                     where o.User_ID == userId
                     select new BasicAccountView { Basic_Details = o, Account_Details = od };
        //var Result = (from o in db.Basic_Details
        //              join od in db.Account_Details on o.User_ID equals od.U_ID
        //              select new Basic_Details { FirstName = od.Name }).ToList();

        return View(Result);
    }
```

Comment: Anyone Up !!! really appreciate it if you could help me in this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the actual value of "this.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name", it may be the problem.
Furthermore, check whether the JOIN query returns any results (exclude the WHERE clause).

I hope it gave you a clue.

Comment: I did check without "this.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name" and it gives me result but guess what !!. it's retrieving whole data, like every row. however, I need data about the logged in user ONLY. already wasted whole week on this error, couldn't find any way to do this.